# Various grid sizes and JPanel elements with GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I am trying to match the following

[image: image pane]

while implementing a GridBagLayout.  The GBL is the only way I know i can get the different sized elements.  I know I can do something like the above picture but I don't know how to do it with GBL.  I am also ready to take suggestions on a better idea.

Comment: BTW - for tips on making great screen-shots, see [How do I create screenshots?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Player GUI]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

class PlayerGui {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        gui.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED));

        JPanel north = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1,5,5));
        north.add(new JLabel("Player Name", SwingConstants.CENTER));

        JPanel tfConstrain = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        tfConstrain.add(new JTextField(18));

        north.add(tfConstrain);

        gui.add(north, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel center = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1,10,10));
        center.add(new JButton("On This Machine"));
        center.add(new JButton("Netowrk Based"));
        center.add(new JButton("Main Menu"));
        center.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(40,70,40,70));

        gui.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please also consider using a `BoxLayout` as outlined by trashgod.  I just tend to reach to my regular 'bag of tricks' when doing layouts and use a nested layout (putting layouts inside other layouts).  Quite lazy of me.  ;)

Answer (score 3):

See [*How to Use BoxLayout*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html), maybe with some [filler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html#filler) and a nice beveled [*Border*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html).