# JLabel in GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout

How to add `JLabel` out of the `GridLayout`?  I have an 8x8 grid layout.

```
Container content = getContentPane();
content.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8,2,2));
for (int f = 0; f < btnArr.length; f++){
    for (int s = 0; s < btnArr.length; s++){
        btnArr[f][s] = new JButton();
        btnArr[f][s].addActionListener(this);
        content.add(btnArr[f][s]);
        btnArr[f][s].setBackground(randomColor());
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I want the 8x8 grid of buttons as well as another label added outside the buttons..

Comment: The trick to this then, would be to put (a panel with) the buttons into a larger layout/panel.  This is known as a [nested layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621338/how-to-add-jtable-in-jpanel/5630271#5630271).  Have a look over the code for that answer and have a go at it yourself.

Comment: I was try it but I can't solve it .... I have to solve this problem as soon please help me.

Comment: @AndrewThompson can't we just manually set `JLabel` it with the help of `setLocation()`?

Comment: Would you provide me the simple example of nested layout ?

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5137250/230513).

Comment: @joeyrohan  `setLocation()` will typically be ignored by a layout manager.  So ..no.  But wait, let me reconsi.. **no.**

Comment: @AndrewThompson yeah right, till the set Layout is != `.setLayout(null)`

Comment: @joeyrohan  re. `null` layout.  Abandon all hope, ye' you enter there!  Sizing and positioning components across different OS', PLAFs, screen resolutions, (...) for a resizable GUI is such complex logic, that you should encapsulate it in a custom layout manager.  See [setLayout(null) is never necessary. Ever!](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1351374) for more details on my take on the matter.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Woha! Thanks alot! It really opened my eyes! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image: SimpleNestedLayout]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class SimpleNestedLayout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5,5));

                int sz = 4;
                Container content = new JPanel(new GridLayout(sz, 0, 2, 2));
                for (int f=0; f<sz*sz; f++) {
                    content.add(new JButton());
                }
                gui.add(content, BorderLayout.CENTER);

                Container info = new JPanel(
                        new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 50, 5));
                info.add(new JLabel("Flow"));
                info.add(new JLabel("Layout"));
                gui.add(info, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

                gui.add(new JLabel("Label"), BorderLayout.LINE_END);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

#### Notes

- For an 8x8 grid, change `sz` to 8.
- If the 'label' mentioned is like the label seen in the GUI, it might go in the outer `BorderLayout` where `Flow` `Layout` (itself a panel) or `Label` appear as well as either of two other vacant positions in the outermost `gui` panel.
- Both `info` (`FlowLayout`) & `content` (`GridLayout`) panels can also accept more components as needed.
- Simple examples of other nested layouts.

  1. [`PlayerGui`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8373943/418556) (31 LOC)
     [image]
  2. [`WestPanel`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12267186/418556) (30 LOC) not a *great* example as it `extends JPanel` instead of simply keeping an instance, but short.
     [image]
  3. [`AmortizationLayout`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10063163/418556) (53 LOC) especially nice as an example as it outlines the parent & child layouts using a titled border.
     [image]